# MySQL COUNT and TOP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table with two columns:

```
NAME        YEAR

Pete        1989
John        1989
Sloane      1990
Derek       1990
Steve       1991
```

I'd like to get the year(s) which occurs the most often, in this case:

```
1989
1990
```

Example #2:

```
NAME        YEAR

Pete        1955
John        1955
Sloane      1990
Derek       1992
Steve       1991
```

In this case:

```
1955
```

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit tricky in MySQL, prior to version 8.0.  Here is one method:

```
select year
from t
group by year
having count(*) = (select count(*)
                   from t
                   group by year
                   order by count(*) desc
                   limit 1
                  );
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c308e/1) is a SQL Fiddle, demonstrating that it works.

Comment: @sasieightynine You might need to add `AND
                 COUNT(*) >= 2` to the outer SQL to make sure the query only works when there are duplicates in the table.. This query will select all records if all years are unique..

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm getting a null row for result but the table that I'm querying from is surely containing the years. For the record, I'm using the `country` table from a factory database called `world` in MySQL Workbench and I'm trying to get the year when the most countries have become independent.

Comment: @sasieightynine . . . I added a SQL Fiddle that shows it working on the data you have provided.